# Does Field order matter in an inner join for access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a query that requires ONE HUNDRED fields to be joined from one table to another. instead of manually going through the query designer, i decided to build the join using excel. When i put the code in to the SQL side of the query,  then clicked designer, it choked on all 100 field comparisons and removed them. i proceeded to manually click drag the entire set of 100 field to join them all. somehow it worked. now when i look at the sql code for how access did it, it looks almost identical to my code. the only difference that i can identify is that instead of it going from A-Z, it goes Z-A. 
Original Query

```
PARAMETERS pn TEXT (255)
,tt TEXT (255)
,sns Long
,sne Long
,ds DATETIME
,de DATETIME;

SELECT y.Short_Description1
,y.Data1
,y.Short_Description2
,y.Data2
,y.Short_Description3
,y.Data3
,y.Short_Description4
,y.Data4
,y.Short_Description5
,y.Data5
,y.Short_Description6
,y.Data6
,y.Short_Description7
,y.Data7
,y.Short_Description8
,y.Data8
,y.Short_Description9
,y.Data9
,y.Short_Description10
,y.Data10
,y.Short_Description11
,y.Data11
,y.Short_Description12
,y.Data12
,y.Short_Description13
,y.Data13
,y.Short_Description14
,y.Data14
,y.Short_Description15
,y.Data15
,y.Short_Description16
,y.Data16
,y.Short_Description17
,y.Data17
,y.Short_Description18
,y.Data18
,y.Short_Description19
,y.Data19
,y.Short_Description20
,y.Data20
,y.Short_Description21
,y.Data21
,y.Short_Description22
,y.Data22
,y.Short_Description23
,y.Data23
,y.Short_Description24
,y.Data24
,y.Short_Description25
,y.Data25
,y.Short_Description26
,y.Data26
,y.Short_Description27
,y.Data27
,y.Short_Description28
,y.Data28
,y.Short_Description29
,y.Data29
,y.Short_Description30
,y.Data30
,y.Short_Description31
,y.Data31
,y.Short_Description32
,y.Data32
,y.Short_Description33
,y.Data33
,y.Short_Description34
,y.Data34
,y.Short_Description35
,y.Data35
,y.Short_Description36
,y.Data36
,y.Short_Description37
,y.Data37
,y.Short_Description38
,y.Data38
,y.Short_Description39
,y.Data39
,y.Short_Description40
,y.Data40
,y.Short_Description41
,y.Data41
,y.Short_Description42
,y.Data42
,y.Short_Description43
,y.Data43
,y.Short_Description44
,y.Data44
,y.Short_Description45
,y.Data45
,y.Short_Description46
,y.Data46
,y.Short_Description47
,y.Data47
,y.Short_Description48
,y.Data48
,y.Short_Description49
,y.Data49
,y.Short_Description50
,y.Data50
,y.Short_Description51
,y.Data51
,y.Short_Description52
,y.Data52
,y.Short_Description53
,y.Data53
,y.Short_Description54
,y.Data54
,y.Short_Description55
,y.Data55
,y.Short_Description56
,y.Data56
,y.Short_Description57
,y.Data57
,y.Short_Description58
,y.Data58
,y.Short_Description59
,y.Data59
,y.Short_Description60
,y.Data60
,y.Short_Description61
,y.Data61
,y.Short_Description62
,y.Data62
,y.Short_Description63
,y.Data63
,y.Short_Description64
,y.Data64
,y.Short_Description65
,y.Data65
,y.Short_Description66
,y.Data66
,y.Short_Description67
,y.Data67
,y.Short_Description68
,y.Data68
,y.Short_Description69
,y.Data69
,y.Short_Description70
,y.Data70
,y.Short_Description71
,y.Data71
,y.Short_Description72
,y.Data72
,y.Short_Description73
,y.Data73
,y.Short_Description74
,y.Data74
,y.Short_Description75
,y.Data75
,y.Short_Description76
,y.Data76
,y.Short_Description77
,y.Data77
,y.Short_Description78
,y.Data78
,y.Short_Description79
,y.Data79
,y.Short_Description80
,y.Data80
,y.Short_Description81
,y.Data81
,y.Short_Description82
,y.Data82
,y.Short_Description83
,y.Data83
,y.Short_Description84
,y.Data84
,y.Short_Description85
,y.Data85
,y.Short_Description86
,y.Data86
,y.Short_Description87
,y.Data87
,y.Short_Description88
,y.Data88
,y.Short_Description89
,y.Data89
,y.Short_Description90
,y.Data90
,y.Short_Description91
,y.Data91
,y.Short_Description92
,y.Data92
,y.Short_Description93
,y.Data93
,y.Short_Description94
,y.Data94
,y.Short_Description95
,y.Data95
,y.Short_Description96
,y.Data96
,y.Short_Description97
,y.Data97
,y.Short_Description98
,y.Data98
,y.Short_Description99
,y.Data99
,y.Short_Description100
,y.Data100
,x.rownum
FROM qryIndividualTestData100Descriptions AS x
INNER JOIN IndividualTestData100 AS y ON (x.Short_Description1 = 
y.Short_Description1)
AND (x.Short_Description2 = y.Short_Description2)
AND (x.Short_Description3 = y.Short_Description3)
AND (x.Short_Description4 = y.Short_Description4)
AND (x.Short_Description5 = y.Short_Description5)
AND (x.Short_Description6 = y.Short_Description6)
AND (x.Short_Description7 = y.Short_Description7)
AND (x.Short_Description8 = y.Short_Description8)
AND (x.Short_Description9 = y.Short_Description9)
AND (x.Short_Description10 = y.Short_Description10)
AND (x.Short_Description11 = y.Short_Description11)
AND (x.Short_Description12 = y.Short_Description12)
AND (x.Short_Description13 = y.Short_Description13)
AND (x.Short_Description14 = y.Short_Description14)
AND (x.Short_Description15 = y.Short_Description15)
AND (x.Short_Description16 = y.Short_Description16)
AND (x.Short_Description17 = y.Short_Description17)
AND (x.Short_Description18 = y.Short_Description18)
AND (x.Short_Description19 = y.Short_Description19)
AND (x.Short_Description20 = y.Short_Description20)
AND (x.Short_Description21 = y.Short_Description21)
AND (x.Short_Description22 = y.Short_Description22)
AND (x.Short_Description23 = y.Short_Description23)
AND (x.Short_Description24 = y.Short_Description24)
AND (x.Short_Description25 = y.Short_Description25)
AND (x.Short_Description26 = y.Short_Description26)
AND (x.Short_Description27 = y.Short_Description27)
AND (x.Short_Description28 = y.Short_Description28)
AND (x.Short_Description29 = y.Short_Description29)
AND (x.Short_Description30 = y.Short_Description30)
AND (x.Short_Description31 = y.Short_Description31)
AND (x.Short_Description32 = y.Short_Description32)
AND (x.Short_Description33 = y.Short_Description33)
AND (x.Short_Description34 = y.Short_Description34)
AND (x.Short_Description35 = y.Short_Description35)
AND (x.Short_Description36 = y.Short_Description36)
AND (x.Short_Description37 = y.Short_Description37)
AND (x.Short_Description38 = y.Short_Description38)
AND (x.Short_Description39 = y.Short_Description39)
AND (x.Short_Description40 = y.Short_Description40)
AND (x.Short_Description41 = y.Short_Description41)
AND (x.Short_Description42 = y.Short_Description42)
AND (x.Short_Description43 = y.Short_Description43)
AND (x.Short_Description44 = y.Short_Description44)
AND (x.Short_Description45 = y.Short_Description45)
AND (x.Short_Description46 = y.Short_Description46)
AND (x.Short_Description47 = y.Short_Description47)
AND (x.Short_Description48 = y.Short_Description48)
AND (x.Short_Description49 = y.Short_Description49)
AND (x.Short_Description50 = y.Short_Description50)
AND (x.Short_Description51 = y.Short_Description51)
AND (x.Short_Description52 = y.Short_Description52)
AND (x.Short_Description53 = y.Short_Description53)
AND (x.Short_Description54 = y.Short_Description54)
AND (x.Short_Description55 = y.Short_Description55)
AND (x.Short_Description56 = y.Short_Description56)
AND (x.Short_Description57 = y.Short_Description57)
AND (x.Short_Description58 = y.Short_Description58)
AND (x.Short_Description59 = y.Short_Description59)
AND (x.Short_Description60 = y.Short_Description60)
AND (x.Short_Description61 = y.Short_Description61)
AND (x.Short_Description62 = y.Short_Description62)
AND (x.Short_Description63 = y.Short_Description63)
AND (x.Short_Description64 = y.Short_Description64)
AND (x.Short_Description65 = y.Short_Description65)
AND (x.Short_Description66 = y.Short_Description66)
AND (x.Short_Description67 = y.Short_Description67)
AND (x.Short_Description68 = y.Short_Description68)
AND (x.Short_Description69 = y.Short_Description69)
AND (x.Short_Description70 = y.Short_Description70)
AND (x.Short_Description71 = y.Short_Description71)
AND (x.Short_Description72 = y.Short_Description72)
AND (x.Short_Description73 = y.Short_Description73)
AND (x.Short_Description74 = y.Short_Description74)
AND (x.Short_Description75 = y.Short_Description75)
AND (x.Short_Description76 = y.Short_Description76)
AND (x.Short_Description77 = y.Short_Description77)
AND (x.Short_Description78 = y.Short_Description78)
AND (x.Short_Description79 = y.Short_Description79)
AND (x.Short_Description80 = y.Short_Description80)
AND (x.Short_Description81 = y.Short_Description81)
AND (x.Short_Description82 = y.Short_Description82)
AND (x.Short_Description83 = y.Short_Description83)
AND (x.Short_Description84 = y.Short_Description84)
AND (x.Short_Description85 = y.Short_Description85)
AND (x.Short_Description86 = y.Short_Description86)
AND (x.Short_Description87 = y.Short_Description87)
AND (x.Short_Description88 = y.Short_Description88)
AND (x.Short_Description89 = y.Short_Description89)
AND (x.Short_Description90 = y.Short_Description90)
AND (x.Short_Description91 = y.Short_Description91)
AND (x.Short_Description92 = y.Short_Description92)
AND (x.Short_Description93 = y.Short_Description93)
AND (x.Short_Description94 = y.Short_Description94)
AND (x.Short_Description95 = y.Short_Description95)
AND (x.Short_Description96 = y.Short_Description96)
AND (x.Short_Description97 = y.Short_Description97)
AND (x.Short_Description98 = y.Short_Description98)
AND (x.Short_Description99 = y.Short_Description99)
AND (x.Short_Description100 = y.Short_Description100)
WHERE (
    ((y.[Part_Number]) LIKE [pn] & "*" & [tt])
    AND (
        (y.[Serial_Number]) >= [sns]
        AND (y.[Serial_Number]) <= [sne]
        )
    AND (
        (y.[Test_Date]) >= [ds]
        AND (y.[Test_Date]) <= [de]
        )
    );
```

Access Generated version

```
PARAMETERS pn TEXT (255)
,tt TEXT (255)
,sns Long
,sne Long
,ds DATETIME
,de DATETIME;

SELECT y.Short_Description1
,y.Data1
,y.Short_Description2
,y.Data2
,y.Short_Description3
,y.Data3
,y.Short_Description4
,y.Data4
,y.Short_Description5
,y.Data5
,y.Short_Description6
,y.Data6
,y.Short_Description7
,y.Data7
,y.Short_Description8
,y.Data8
,y.Short_Description9
,y.Data9
,y.Short_Description10
,y.Data10
,y.Short_Description11
,y.Data11
,y.Short_Description12
,y.Data12
,y.Short_Description13
,y.Data13
,y.Short_Description14
,y.Data14
,y.Short_Description15
,y.Data15
,y.Short_Description16
,y.Data16
,y.Short_Description17
,y.Data17
,y.Short_Description18
,y.Data18
,y.Short_Description19
,y.Data19
,y.Short_Description20
,y.Data20
,y.Short_Description21
,y.Data21
,y.Short_Description22
,y.Data22
,y.Short_Description23
,y.Data23
,y.Short_Description24
,y.Data24
,y.Short_Description25
,y.Data25
,y.Short_Description26
,y.Data26
,y.Short_Description27
,y.Data27
,y.Short_Description28
,y.Data28
,y.Short_Description29
,y.Data29
,y.Short_Description30
,y.Data30
,y.Short_Description31
,y.Data31
,y.Short_Description32
,y.Data32
,y.Short_Description33
,y.Data33
,y.Short_Description34
,y.Data34
,y.Short_Description35
,y.Data35
,y.Short_Description36
,y.Data36
,y.Short_Description37
,y.Data37
,y.Short_Description38
,y.Data38
,y.Short_Description39
,y.Data39
,y.Short_Description40
,y.Data40
,y.Short_Description41
,y.Data41
,y.Short_Description42
,y.Data42
,y.Short_Description43
,y.Data43
,y.Short_Description44
,y.Data44
,y.Short_Description45
,y.Data45
,y.Short_Description46
,y.Data46
,y.Short_Description47
,y.Data47
,y.Short_Description48
,y.Data48
,y.Short_Description49
,y.Data49
,y.Short_Description50
,y.Data50
,y.Short_Description51
,y.Data51
,y.Short_Description52
,y.Data52
,y.Short_Description53
,y.Data53
,y.Short_Description54
,y.Data54
,y.Short_Description55
,y.Data55
,y.Short_Description56
,y.Data56
,y.Short_Description57
,y.Data57
,y.Short_Description58
,y.Data58
,y.Short_Description59
,y.Data59
,y.Short_Description60
,y.Data60
,y.Short_Description61
,y.Data61
,y.Short_Description62
,y.Data62
,y.Short_Description63
,y.Data63
,y.Short_Description64
,y.Data64
,y.Short_Description65
,y.Data65
,y.Short_Description66
,y.Data66
,y.Short_Description67
,y.Data67
,y.Short_Description68
,y.Data68
,y.Short_Description69
,y.Data69
,y.Short_Description70
,y.Data70
,y.Short_Description71
,y.Data71
,y.Short_Description72
,y.Data72
,y.Short_Description73
,y.Data73
,y.Short_Description74
,y.Data74
,y.Short_Description75
,y.Data75
,y.Short_Description76
,y.Data76
,y.Short_Description77
,y.Data77
,y.Short_Description78
,y.Data78
,y.Short_Description79
,y.Data79
,y.Short_Description80
,y.Data80
,y.Short_Description81
,y.Data81
,y.Short_Description82
,y.Data82
,y.Short_Description83
,y.Data83
,y.Short_Description84
,y.Data84
,y.Short_Description85
,y.Data85
,y.Short_Description86
,y.Data86
,y.Short_Description87
,y.Data87
,y.Short_Description88
,y.Data88
,y.Short_Description89
,y.Data89
,y.Short_Description90
,y.Data90
,y.Short_Description91
,y.Data91
,y.Short_Description92
,y.Data92
,y.Short_Description93
,y.Data93
,y.Short_Description94
,y.Data94
,y.Short_Description95
,y.Data95
,y.Short_Description96
,y.Data96
,y.Short_Description97
,y.Data97
,y.Short_Description98
,y.Data98
,y.Short_Description99
,y.Data99
,y.Short_Description100
,y.Data100
,x.rownum
FROM qryIndividualTestData100Descriptions AS x
INNER JOIN individualtestdata100 AS y ON (x.Short_Description100 = 
y.Short_Description100)
AND (x.Short_Description99 = y.Short_Description99)
AND (x.Short_Description98 = y.Short_Description98)
AND (x.Short_Description97 = y.Short_Description97)
AND (x.Short_Description96 = y.Short_Description96)
AND (x.Short_Description95 = y.Short_Description95)
AND (x.Short_Description94 = y.Short_Description94)
AND (x.Short_Description93 = y.Short_Description93)
AND (x.Short_Description92 = y.Short_Description92)
AND (x.Short_Description91 = y.Short_Description91)
AND (x.Short_Description90 = y.Short_Description90)
AND (x.Short_Description89 = y.Short_Description89)
AND (x.Short_Description88 = y.Short_Description88)
AND (x.Short_Description87 = y.Short_Description87)
AND (x.Short_Description86 = y.Short_Description86)
AND (x.Short_Description85 = y.Short_Description85)
AND (x.Short_Description84 = y.Short_Description84)
AND (x.Short_Description83 = y.Short_Description83)
AND (x.Short_Description82 = y.Short_Description82)
AND (x.Short_Description81 = y.Short_Description81)
AND (x.Short_Description80 = y.Short_Description80)
AND (x.Short_Description79 = y.Short_Description79)
AND (x.Short_Description78 = y.Short_Description78)
AND (x.Short_Description77 = y.Short_Description77)
AND (x.Short_Description76 = y.Short_Description76)
AND (x.Short_Description75 = y.Short_Description75)
AND (x.Short_Description74 = y.Short_Description74)
AND (x.Short_Description73 = y.Short_Description73)
AND (x.Short_Description72 = y.Short_Description72)
AND (x.Short_Description71 = y.Short_Description71)
AND (x.Short_Description70 = y.Short_Description70)
AND (x.Short_Description69 = y.Short_Description69)
AND (x.Short_Description68 = y.Short_Description68)
AND (x.Short_Description67 = y.Short_Description67)
AND (x.Short_Description66 = y.Short_Description66)
AND (x.Short_Description65 = y.Short_Description65)
AND (x.Short_Description64 = y.Short_Description64)
AND (x.Short_Description63 = y.Short_Description63)
AND (x.Short_Description62 = y.Short_Description62)
AND (x.Short_Description61 = y.Short_Description61)
AND (x.Short_Description60 = y.Short_Description60)
AND (x.Short_Description59 = y.Short_Description59)
AND (x.Short_Description58 = y.Short_Description58)
AND (x.Short_Description57 = y.Short_Description57)
AND (x.Short_Description56 = y.Short_Description56)
AND (x.Short_Description55 = y.Short_Description55)
AND (x.Short_Description54 = y.Short_Description54)
AND (x.Short_Description53 = y.Short_Description53)
AND (x.Short_Description52 = y.Short_Description52)
AND (x.Short_Description51 = y.Short_Description51)
AND (x.Short_Description50 = y.Short_Description50)
AND (x.Short_Description49 = y.Short_Description49)
AND (x.Short_Description48 = y.Short_Description48)
AND (x.Short_Description47 = y.Short_Description47)
AND (x.Short_Description46 = y.Short_Description46)
AND (x.Short_Description45 = y.Short_Description45)
AND (x.Short_Description44 = y.Short_Description44)
AND (x.Short_Description43 = y.Short_Description43)
AND (x.Short_Description42 = y.Short_Description42)
AND (x.Short_Description41 = y.Short_Description41)
AND (x.Short_Description40 = y.Short_Description40)
AND (x.Short_Description39 = y.Short_Description39)
AND (x.Short_Description38 = y.Short_Description38)
AND (x.Short_Description37 = y.Short_Description37)
AND (x.Short_Description36 = y.Short_Description36)
AND (x.Short_Description35 = y.Short_Description35)
AND (x.Short_Description34 = y.Short_Description34)
AND (x.Short_Description33 = y.Short_Description33)
AND (x.Short_Description32 = y.Short_Description32)
AND (x.Short_Description31 = y.Short_Description31)
AND (x.Short_Description30 = y.Short_Description30)
AND (x.Short_Description29 = y.Short_Description29)
AND (x.Short_Description28 = y.Short_Description28)
AND (x.Short_Description27 = y.Short_Description27)
AND (x.Short_Description26 = y.Short_Description26)
AND (x.Short_Description25 = y.Short_Description25)
AND (x.Short_Description24 = y.Short_Description24)
AND (x.Short_Description23 = y.Short_Description23)
AND (x.Short_Description22 = y.Short_Description22)
AND (x.Short_Description21 = y.Short_Description21)
AND (x.Short_Description20 = y.Short_Description20)
AND (x.Short_Description19 = y.Short_Description19)
AND (x.Short_Description18 = y.Short_Description18)
AND (x.Short_Description17 = y.Short_Description17)
AND (x.Short_Description16 = y.Short_Description16)
AND (x.Short_Description15 = y.Short_Description15)
AND (x.Short_Description14 = y.Short_Description14)
AND (x.Short_Description13 = y.Short_Description13)
AND (x.Short_Description12 = y.Short_Description12)
AND (x.Short_Description11 = y.Short_Description11)
AND (x.Short_Description10 = y.Short_Description10)
AND (x.Short_Description9 = y.Short_Description9)
AND (x.Short_Description8 = y.Short_Description8)
AND (x.Short_Description7 = y.Short_Description7)
AND (x.Short_Description6 = y.Short_Description6)
AND (x.Short_Description5 = y.Short_Description5)
AND (x.Short_Description4 = y.Short_Description4)
AND (x.Short_Description3 = y.Short_Description3)
AND (x.Short_Description2 = y.Short_Description2)
AND (x.Short_Description1 = y.Short_Description1)
WHERE (
    ((y.Part_Number) LIKE [pn] & "*" & [tt])
    AND (
        (y.Serial_Number) >= [sns]
        AND (y.Serial_Number) <= [sne]
        )
    AND (
        (y.Test_Date) >= [ds]
        AND (y.Test_Date) <= [de]
        )
    );
```

Why does access choke on the query?

Comment: Field ordering 100% doesn't matter. I suspect it choked because your ON clause is borderline insane. I think you should take it as a clue that your schema is bad. How can it be that the only relationship between two tables is defined with over 100 field comparisons?

Comment: i didnt make the tables, i just have to deal with the absolute garbage design. the engineer who designed it doesnt work here anymore. fortunately i have convinced them to move to a MUCH saner schema on SQL server.
basically this table stores test data and the tests can change. so i have to find unique groups of descriptions. so that when i am exporting data from this and converting those descriptions to columns, different groups of descriptions goto different sheets.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I suspect that Access is just choking when parsing the query  to show the visual representation of the join when you define it with straight SQL. I've never seen that happen before, but I've never seen someone join on 100+ fields before too. I imagine doing this in the GUI is pretty tedious. If you go to the SQL view and paste in your own query, if you avoid the "Design View" will it still run?

Comment: sadly its looking like neither query is working. back to the drawing board i guess

Comment: Not sure if access could handle this...it's memory allocation in joins have been troublesome for me in the past at 4 to 5 columns in a join statement let alone 100...I'm still unsure if access is a database or a series of linked excel sheets really.  Heh, thats beyond ugly.  Any chance you could get this data out of access and into a different database?

Comment: That's not just insane, it's clearly a candidate for The Daily WTF.  It's hard to fathom that there isn't an id number or some sort of name that isn't common or could be mapped between the two tables.  But to answer the question, I agree, field order doesn't matter.

Comment: An old C based application was hard coded to use that particular table with that particular schema. I had to processes the table to get unique groupings of the short descriptions (because order matters on those). so i use grouping to establish the unique groups and give them a number so i can refer to them that way in a vba script. i need to join those together so that i can sort the data going into an excel spreadsheet (where those descriptions are now columns) into separate sheets. The whole thing is pretty nuts, but thats what my bosses asked me to do. there is a 10 20 30 40 50 60 as well.